# How to list all files in folder and subfolders based on file attributes, specifically files with the ALOM attribute (windows 10)?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, extract

I'm trying to extract a list of files in a folder and the subfolders based on specific file attributes. As it's much more reliable then me doing it by hand, especially considering it's far over a 1000 files.

Some files need to be recovered and they need to know which ones, so files that have the "ALOM" attribute aren't available, available files have "RAL" or "AL" attributes.

I know I can extract a list of all files using the CMD with the command *dir \s nameofsavedlist.txt* however I couldn't find what to use to only extract files based on file attributes.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So after trying to figure this out for a while, it seems like microsoft didn't update their documentation.

ALOM means they have the offline attribute which is addressed by the letter o which wasn't on the microsoft website. So you can access it by addressing the attributes with the letter o, like /a:o. Below is what I used in the folder to extract all the files. Maybe it helps other people when trying to figure out the same.

```
dir /a:o /s > filenamesOFF.txt
```

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, you should see the following under `/A          Displays files with specified attributes.`, `L  Reparse Points             O  Offline files`. _You should always check the documentation built into the commands or system before searching the internet for it!_